# populating products from xml on into magento catalog

Tags: configurable-product, xml, cron

I am looking to develop an automated system for inventory but got no pointers on how to, there is a product XML from a shop with product meta information, which my Magento store should read through after x number of minutes and fill in the inventory depending on code for `<attr>` code or delete, modify it, I will try to best illustrate this

```
<product>Playstation 4</product>
<sku>00123</sku>
<desc>A very cool console</desc>
<img></img>
<attr></attr>
```

That is an excerpt/example of an XML file which will be imported from an FTP server after successful login, how can I use that info to map those to my Magento store and sync my store level.